# docker-compose volumes: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following folder structure:

```
scripts/
--constraints.cypher
docker-compose.yml
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  app-config-db:
    image: neo4j:latest
    container_name: app-config-db
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/var/lib/neo4j/scripts
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test123!
    command:
      - cypher-shell -u neo4j -p test123! --file /var/lib/neo4j/scripts/constraints.cypher
```

But when I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

> error: exec: "cypher-shell -u neo4j -p test123! --file /var/lib/neo4j/scripts/constraints.cypher": stat cypher-shell -u neo4j -p test123! --file /var/lib/neo4j/scripts/constraints.cypher: no such file or directory

To me, it seems like the `.scripts` directory is not mounting correctly into my docker container, but everything seems in order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scripts` directory gets mounted correctly. The problem here is that you are specifying the command in an array form so docker searches for the executable file `"cypher-shell -u neo4j -p test123! --file /var/lib/neo4j/scripts/constraints.cypher"` which is obviously not found. You can either specify the command as a string

```yaml
services:
  app-config-db:
    image: neo4j:latest
    container_name: app-config-db
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/var/lib/neo4j/scripts
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test123!
    command: cypher-shell -u neo4j -p test123! --file /var/lib/neo4j/scripts/constraints.cypher
```

Or split all the options up:

```yaml
services:
  app-config-db:
    image: neo4j:latest
    container_name: app-config-db
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/var/lib/neo4j/scripts
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test123!
    command:
      - cypher-shell
      - -u
      - neo4j
      - -p
      - test123!
      - --file
      - /var/lib/neo4j/scripts/constraints.cypher
```

This is similar to the `CMD` instruction in the Dockerfile. You can find more info in the [compose file spec](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) and the documentation for [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).